# Pessimistic Locking with_lock in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, locking

In our rails app, we have a model say `Person` and the corresponding table in mysql database has around million records. We have a method in our controller `update_status` to a particular attribute `status`. We are receiving a lot of update HTTP requests on this model. It is highly transactional in nature at times we are getting multiple updates on a particular record within one second. We are noticing some mysql timeouts from the logs.

My theory is it resulted in mysql deadlock because of so many updates happening within second on a particular record. As a resolution, I am planning to use with_lock while doing an update as below:

```
def update_status
  @person_object.with_lock do
     @person.update_attribute(:status, params[:status])
  end
  render response
end
```

Earlier we didn't have a lock and now I am introducing this `with_lock` to handle this issue. What kind of performance implication this will have, considering the traffic is very high? While I am aware `with_lock` does a `row-level locking` I am not sure if I have to be mindful of any other impact this change might cause. Even if it is not caused by `deadlock`, is it a good practice to use such locks on such frequently updated methods/columns. Looking for your inputs. Thanks.